# What command to use in visual studio 2017 to obtain the functionality of clrscr() in c++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017

clrscr() does not work in visual studio 2017.I tried system("cls") including windows.h and conio.h header file still it gives error.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: 'clrscr' :identifier not found

Comment: `clrscr()` and `conio.h`   - really? What were you previously using? Turbo C++? (Which is some 20 years old and not remotely standard compliant)..

Comment: Well, if you wanna use `system("cls")` you need to include the header `<cstdlib>`.